# Python package installer (pip) does nothing in Windows

Tags: python, windows-xp, pip, python-module, package-managers

Having installed pip (as Admin) under Windows XP, when I run it nothing apparently happens, even if I just type "pip" or "pip --verbose" or something obviously wrong like "pip xxx".

pip was installed by running get-pip.py from within a python 2.7.4 shell. This gave no errors and appears to have worked correctly as I can now successfully run commands from within python:

```
>>> pip.main(['uninstall', 'Fiona'])
>>> pip.main(['install', 'Fiona'])
```

I would be happy to just run it from within python, but I cannot find documentation for how to pass other command line arguments to the module - my big problem is that it tries to install packages in the version of Python marked in my registry, rather than the intended QGIS python install, even when I have set PATH and PYTHONPATH to point to the QGIS version. Thus options like "--ignore-installed" look likely to be helpful.

Comment: Maybe offtopic but: You shouldn't use Windows XP anymore for anything connected to a network.